# R - Append rows from dataframe to another one without duplicate on "primary keys columns"

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, key

I have two dataframes (A and B). B contains new values and A contains outdated values.

Each of these dataframes have one column representing the key and another one representing the value.

I want to add rows from B to A and then clean rows that contain duplicated keys from A (update A with the new values that are in B). Order doesn't really matter, I think it is easier in the other order : cleaning duplicates and then appending.

---

At the moment, I have done this script :

```
A <- bind_rows(B, A)
A <- A[!duplicated(A),]
```

The issue I have is that it doesn't clean rows because they are not real duplicates (value is different).

How could I handle this?

Comment: Try `A[!duplicated(A$key),]`

Comment: Re "easier in the other order": `bind_rows(A,B) %>% filter(!duplicated(key, fromLast=TRUE))` should work. (I'd answer, but there's no example so I'm not sure my code works / meets expectations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a hunch because there's no example data provided, but I suspect a merge is a much safer approach than a row-bind:

**Solution with data.table**

```
library(data.table)
```

1 - Rename variables to prepare for a merge

```
setnames(A, old="value", new="value_A")
setnames(B, old="value", new="value_B")
```

2 - Merge, be sure to use the `all` arg

```
dt <- merge(A, B, by="key", all=TRUE)
```

3 - Use some rule for the update - for example: use `value_B` unless it's missing, in which case use `value_A`

```
dt[ , value := value_B]
dt[is.na(value), value := value_A]
```

**Solution with Base R**

```
names(A) <- c("key", "value_A")
names(B) <- c("key", "value_B")

df <- merge(A, B, by="key", all=TRUE)

df$value <- df$value_B
df[is.na(df$value), "value"] <- df[is.na(df$value), "value_A"]
```

**Solution with dplyr/tidyverse**

```
library(dplyr)

df <- full_join(A, B, by="key") %>% 
      mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value_B), value_A, value_B))
```

*Example Data*

```
set.seed(1234)
A <- data.frame(
    key = sample(1:50, size=20),
    value = runif(20, 1, 10))

B <- data.frame(
    key = sample(1:50, size=20),
    value = runif(20, 1, 10))
```